# On clicking a button to add elements to an array in javascript, each time console.logging the array is returned with one less element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

On, clicking a button to add an item to an array initialised as cart, the added item immediately appears in the cart array however, when I console.log the array, the item added does not get shown until after the next click. In that the first time the add button is clicked and the cart array console.logged; an empty array is returned. On the second click, the cart array is returned with only one item, the one supposedly added on the first click and so on, yet when I call a map method on the cart array, all the added elements are present. Why does it seem as though there is a delay?

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const addItem = (prod, index) => {
    setCart([...cart, prod]);
    console.log(cart);//seems to have a delay, one less item featured each click
  };

return (
    <>
      <div className="cartItems">
        {cart.map((prod, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={prod.id} className="">
              <h2 className="itemTitle">{prod.name}</h2>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>

      <div className="itemsContainer">
        {products.map((prod, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={prod.id} className="itemContainer">
              <img
                src={prod.src}
                alt={prod.name}
                className="itemImage"
              />
              <h2 className="itemTitle">{prod.name}</h2>
              <span className="itemPrice">{prod.priceN}</span>
              <button
                className="itemButton"
                onClick={() => {
                  addItem(prod, index);
                }}
              >
                Order
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't get the correct value from state variable after setting it up.**

You updated your state value `cart` by `setCart([...cart, prod]);`.
Then you tried to print `cart` at the next line.

```
  const addItem = (prod, index) => {
    setCart([...cart, prod]);
    console.log(cart);//seems to have a delay, one less item featured each click
  };
```

But it doesn't work. Because setState works asynchronously in React.

**Here is the statement in Reactjs official document.**

> **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**
>
> React may batch multiple setState()
> calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
> should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

To know the updated state value, please use `useEffect` hook.

**You can print the updated state value like the following:**

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(cart);
}, [cart]);
```